# How to understand elements of the scheme $GL_n$ as linear isomorphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let as usual $GL_n$ be the scheme given by the equation $$det(\{x_{kl}\}_{1\leq k,l\leq n})y=1$$ in $\mathbb{A}^{{n^2}+1}$. I have seen that one considers elements of $GL_n$ likewise as linear isomorphisms $\mathbb{A}^n\to\mathbb{A}^n$ of schemes. I want to understand what this means formally and it would be nice if something like the following holds:

Perhaps the scheme $GL_n$ *represents* some functor of points $L:Sch^{op}\to Sets$ which in turn can easily be identified with linear isomorphisms $\mathbb{A}^n\to\mathbb{A}^n$. In other words, there is perhaps an isomorphism
$$
Hom_{Sch}(-,GL_n)\cong L(-)
$$
of functors from $Sch^{op}$ to $Sets$.

What could this functor $L$ be? Perhaps $L(V)$ is the set of linear isomorphisms $\mathbb{A}^n\times V\to\mathbb{A}^n\times V$ of schemes? This is a functor from $Sch^{op}$ to $Sets$ by pulling back along $\mathbb{A}^n\times f$ for a morphism $f:W\to V$ in $Sch$ but this is just a guess for $L$.

My question is:

> Is there a way to understand $GL_n$ in these terms as the representing
>   object of a certain functor $L(-)$ which can easily be
>   identified with the linear isomorphisms $\mathbb{A}^n\to\mathbb{A}^n$?

I know that an $R$-point of $GL_n$ can be viewed as an invertible $(n\times n)$-matrix $\{a_{kl}\}_{1\leq k,l\leq n}$ with entries in $R$. This defines a linear morphism $\mathbb{A}^n\times V\to\mathbb{A}^n\times V$ where $V=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ through an automomorphism on $R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ sending $x_k$ to $\sum_{l=0}^n a_{kl} x_l$ (I hope this is correct). The question is, how to express this fact precisely in the language above.

Comment: It seems to me like the last paragraph already answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is standard and can be found in any book on algebraic groups. The scheme $\mathrm{GL}_n$ represents the contravariant functor $X \mapsto \mathrm{GL}_n(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ (actually this is the functorial *definition* of $\mathrm{GL}_n$). For a commutative ring $R$, the group $\mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ is isomorphic to the group of linear automorphisms of $\mathbb{A}^n_R$.

If $X$ is an arbitrary scheme, then one has to be careful as for the definition of linear. In topology one usually demands this fiberwise, but this does not suffice here when $X$ is not reduced. A morphism $\mathbb{A}^n_X \to \mathbb{A}^m_X$ is called linear if for every $X$-scheme $T$ the induced map on $T$-valued points $\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)^n \to \Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)^m$ is $\Gamma(T,\mathcal{O}_T)$-linear. Then it is induced by a matrix, and all these matrices have to be compatible. We see that the linear morphisms correspond to $M_{m \times n}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$. In particular, the linear automorphisms of $\mathbb{A}^n_X$ correspond to $\mathrm{GL}_n(X)$.

Comment: Dear @Martin, thank you for the answer. You are saying in particular that the functor $X\mapsto LinIso_X(\mathbb{A}^n_X,\mathbb{A}^n_X)$ (the subscript means ''over $X$'') is representable by $GL_n$ as a functor from (the opposite category of) affine schemes but it is **not** representable by $GL_n$ as a functor from $Sch^{op}$, right? Do you know an example for your last statement or a reference?

Comment: I have refined  my answer.

Comment: Dear @Martin, thank you for the refinement. When you want to show the existence of an isomorphism $Hom_{Sch}(X,GL_n)\cong M_{n\times n}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$, I wondered how you construct a morphism $Hom_{Sch}(X,GL_n)\to M_{n\times n}(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ natural in $X$ in the first place. Does this work as you cite (http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04TP) in your other answer, i.e. you first show that both $Hom_{Sch}(-,GL_n)$ and $M_{n\times n}(\Gamma(-,\mathcal{O}_{-}))$ are sheaves, you construct a morphism locally and then check compatibility?

Comment: No. We have $\mathrm{GL}_n(X):=\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathrm{GL}_n) \cong \mathrm{GL}_n(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$. This follows immediately from the more general bijection $\hom(X,\mathrm{Spec}(A)) \cong \hom(A,\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X))$ and the universal property of polynomial rings and quotients applied to $A=k[\{x_{kl}\},y]/(\text{blupp})$.

Comment: Dear @Martin, ok, thank you.